# Problema intentando hacer una union de dos consultas mysql de dos tablas diferentes en una sola funcion php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Hola el problema que presento es que al momento de ejecutar las consultas solo me esta ejecutando la consulta de la tabla ejemplo2 y no la consulta de la tabla ejemplo1 nose si es que tengo mal la union las tablas tienen la misma estructura para informacion diferentes.

```
$query  = " SELECT a.id, a.nombre
                FROM ejemplo1 a
                ";
        $query .= " UNION ";
        $query  = " SELECT a.id,a.nombre
                FROM ejemplo2 a
                ";
    $query  .= " WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

Comment: Ejecuta primero por separado las 2 consultas y ve que te devuelve.

Answer (score 0):

Ajusta la consulta para que agregue la segunda parte (en `$query  = " SELECT a.id,a.nombre`). Asegurarse de usar `.=` para agregar texto:

```
$query  = " SELECT a.id, a.nombre
            FROM ejemplo1 a
            ";
$query .= " UNION ";
$query .= " SELECT a.id,a.nombre
            FROM ejemplo2 a
            ";
$query  .= " WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

Ademas, ten en cuenta que el comportamiento de `UNION` es intentar devolver todas las filas distintas entre las uniones (no las repite si tienen los mismos datos). Si deseas incluir todos los registros unidos debes usar `UNION ALL`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp